# How to print iterated value from mongoDB objects

Tags: java, mongodb, loops, iterator

I have values that are coming from MongoDB and getting stored in a DBObject. After that I am doing a `find` on it as shown in the below code -

```
for (String abc: listA) {

    BasicDBObject f1 = new BasicDBObject("lk", abc);
    DBObject test = container.findOne(f1);

    for (String key: test.keySet()) {
        System.out.println("key: " + key+ " value: " + test.get(key)); //Line1
    }

    // how to iterate test.get(key) and prints out all the values one by one
}
```

From `Line 1` I am getting the following as print on my console:

```
key: mystic value: [ "notAThingToSee" , "everyThingIsPossible"]
```

Now, I need to iterate `test.get(key)` in such a way such that it prints out the data one by one in a new line, something like this -

```
notAThingToSee
everyThingIsPossible
```

Is this possible to do? I tried doing it but I got an error that `for each is not applicable to java.lang.Object`

```
for (Object ss : test.get("mystic")) {
    System.out.println("SS: " + ss); //Line 2
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array of `value` will come back as a [BasicDBList](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/BasicDBList.html), not an array of Objects. Try something like (haven't compiled this...):

```
DBObject test = container.findOne(f1);
BasicDBList values = (BasicDBList) test.get("value");

for (Object value : values) {
    System.out.println(value);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Peter, I am getting the following error on this `BasicDBList values = (BasicDBList) test.next().get("value");` line saying `Cannot resolve method 'next()'`  Any help on this would be great :)